# iPad Pro iPadOS 14.5, last highlights and notes on Books is lost every time I close Books or shut down

Tags: ipad, books, ipados, highlights

When I close Books app on my iPad Pro iPadOS 14.5, or when I turn off my iPad, the next time I open Books some of my last highlights and notes on the book I was reading the last time are gone. Any ideas on to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS and iPadOS 14.5 are currently beta operating systems and are expected to have bugs and other random issues. As of this writing, they are on developer beta 2 and public beta 1. There will likely be over 5 betas before this version is officially released.

You should not use beta software on your primary devices or on any devices on which you depend. You should report any bugs you find to Apple using the Feedback app (purple/pink icon) that appears on your Home Screen or app drawer when you install beta software on your Apple devices. If you are not willing to live with bugs/issues and report them to Apple, you should not install beta software.

There’s nothing anyone here can do to help you with beta Apple software. If you report the bugs to Apple, they will likely fix it before releasing the final version.

You can either downgrade your device to a final version of iPadOS such as 14.4 (recommended) or wait until the next beta is released and hope it is fixed by then, but there are no guarantees about beta software and the next version could actually be worse than the current one you have.

### Reinstall Apple Books

Sometimes with beta software resetting settings, apps or even the whole device might work. You can try reinstalling Apple Books.

1. Make a backup of all of your files. PDFs, books and anything you have imported into Apple Books. You already have a backup if you use iCloud and Apple Books and iCloud Drive are enabled on Preferences > Your Name > iCloud. Make sure the backup has finished synchronization before proceeding.

Delete the Apple Books app and download it again from the App Store. Then try again and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: How to downgrade to 14.4?

Comment: Do you think this problem is related to the Beta version too: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414106/words-are-selected-in-a-weird-way-in-ipad-pro-books

Comment: @Sasan It is _possible_ that your other question is also caused by a beta bug. I can't test that because as I'm a developer I'm also running the 14.5 developer beta on my iPad. If you didn't have this issue before installing the 14.5 beta, just downgrade. **Make sure to backup all your data before downgrading.** Here's a downgrade tutorial: https://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/ios-tutorials/how-to-downgrade-ios/

Comment: So could you please see if you have that bug on your beta too? Just highlight some parts on a book on Books, close it, and then open it again, see if the last highlights are gone. It doesn’t happen always on my iPad, though.

Comment: @Sasan sure. I've just tried it: opened the book I was reading (purchased from Apple Books), highlighted some random text then immediatelly closed Apple Books. Upon reopening the app, the highlights were still there. I tried it a few times doing things in different orders to see if I could reproduce the issue but the highlights were always saved correctly. I'm using the yellow text highlight and I didn't change color or settings, I just held my finger and dragged text. 2018 iPad Pro 12.9" running iPadOS 14.5 developer beta 2. Keep in mind public betas and developer betas are slightly different

Comment: @Sasan I've added instructions on how to reinstall Apple Books. It's a lot easier and faster to do than downgrading and could help you, considering I don't have the issue. Are you running the public beta or the developer beta?

Comment: Public one. I am not a developer.